# Php: How to list static fields/properties through reflection?

Tags: php, reflection, static-members

Let's say I have this class:

```
class Example {    
    public static $FOO = array('id'=>'foo', 'length'=>23, 'height'=>34.2);
    public static $BAR = array('id'=>'bar', 'length'=>22.5, 'height'=>96.223);
}
```

How could I use reflection to get a list of the static fields? (Something like array('$FOO', '$BAR')?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [`ReflectionClass][1]`. The [`getProperties()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php) function will return an array of [`ReflectionProperty`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php) objects. The `ReflectionProperty` object have a [`isStatic()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.isstatic.php) method which will tell you whether the property is static or not and a [`getName()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.getname.php) method that return the name.

**Example:**

```
<?php

class Example {    
    public static $FOO = array('id'=>'foo', 'length'=>23, 'height'=>34.2);
    public static $BAR = array('id'=>'bar', 'length'=>22.5, 'height'=>96.223);
}

$reflection = new ReflectionClass('Example'); 
$properties = $reflection->getProperties();
$static = array();

if ( ! empty($properties) )
  foreach ( $properties as $property )
    if ( $property->isStatic() )
      $static[] = $property->getName();

print_r($static);
```